# Windows 10 Send To Menu is completely random

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, send-to

I have customized my Send To menu by editing `C:\Users\terry.aney\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo`.  I've put the following shortcuts in there:

[image]

If I use a mouse and right click a file (in this case `\Downloads\*.pow` file), I *think* it always behaves and shows the **correct** menu like (during the last 5 minutes of testing I couldn't get it to show wrong menu):

[image]

However, almost every time I want to get to the Send To menu, I use the keyboard.  <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>F10</kbd> is my preferred method, but I've a <kbd>Fn</kbd>-<kbd>RightCtrl</kbd> option available to me as well.  When I use the keyboard method, many more times that not, I get one of the two following menus appear (note, sometimes, it does show the correct menu, but not often and I can't figure out a pattern unfortunately):

[image]

or:

[image]

How can I make the Send To menu always/only show what is in the `SendTo` folder?